# Torch: collectgarbage() not deallocating memory of torch tensors

Tags: memory-leaks, lua, garbage-collection, torch

I am running a code that has following structure:

```
network = createNetwork() -- loading a pre-trained network. 
function train()
    for i=1,#trainingsamples do
        local ip = loadInput()
        local ip_1 = someImageProcessing(ip)
        local ip_2 = someImageProcessing(ip)
        network:forward( ...some manipulation on ip_1,ip_2...)
        network:backward()
        collectgarbage('collect')
        print debug.getlocal -- all local variables.
        end
end
```

I am expecting that collectgarbage() will release all the memory held by ip_1, ip_2, and ip. But I could see the memory is not released. This causes memory leak. I am wondering what's happening. Can someone please help me in understanding the strange behavior of collectgarbage() and fixing the memory leak.

I am really sorry that I could not add the full code. Hope the snippet I have added is sufficient to understand the flow of my code and my network training code is very similar to a standard CNN training code.

EDIT:

Sorry for not mentioning the variables were declared local and using a keyword for a variable in the sample snippet. I have edited it now. The only global variable is the network which is declared outside of the train function and I feed ip_1, ip_2 as inputs to the network. Also I have added trimmed version of my actual code below.

```
network = createNetwork()

function trainNetwork()

local parameters,gradParameters = network:getParameters()
network:training()    -- set flag for dropout

local bs = 1 

local lR = params.learning_rate / torch.sqrt(bs) 
local optimConfig = {learningRate = params.learning_rate,
                   momentum = params.momentum,
                   learningRateDecay = params.lr_decay,
                   beta1 = params.optim_beta1,
                   beta2 = params.optim_beta2,
                   epsilon = params.optim_epsilon}

 local nfiles = getNoofFiles('train')

 local weights = torch.Tensor(params.num_classes):fill(1)

 criterion =  nn.ClassNLLCriterion(weights)

for ep=1,params.epochs do


IMAGE_SEQ = 1

while (IMAGE_SEQ <= nfiles) do

  xlua.progress(IMAGE_SEQ, nfiles)
  local input, inputd2
  local color_image, depth_image2, target_image


  local nextInput = loadNext('train')
  color_image = nextInput.data.rgb
  depth_image2 = nextInput.data.depth
  target_image = nextInput.data.labels

  input = network0:forward(color_image)       -- process RGB
  inputd2 = networkd:forward(depth_image2):squeeze()   -- HHA

  local input_concat = torch.cat(input,inputd2,1):squeeze()  -- concat RGB,  HHA
  collectgarbage('collect')


  target = target_image:reshape(params.imWidth*params.imHeight) -- reshape target as vector


  -- create closure to evaluate f(X) and df/dX
  local loss = 0
  local feval = function(x)
    -- get new parameters
  if x ~= parameters then parameters:copy(x) end
    collectgarbage()

    -- reset gradients
    gradParameters:zero()
    -- f is the average of all criterions
    -- evaluate function for complete mini batch


    local output = network:forward(input_concat)    -- run forward pass
    local err = criterion:forward(output, target)   -- compute loss

    loss = loss + err


-- estimate df/dW
    local df_do = criterion:backward(output, target)

    network:backward(input_concat, df_do)           -- update parameters

      local _,predicted_labels = torch.max(output,2)
      predicted_labels = torch.reshape(predicted_labels:squeeze():float(),params.imHeight,params.imWidth)


    return err,gradParameters
  end -- feval

  pm('Training loss: '.. loss, 3)

  _,current_loss = optim.adam(feval, parameters, optimConfig)
  print ('epoch / current_loss ',ep,current_loss[1])

  os.execute('cat /proc/$PPID/status | grep RSS')

  collectgarbage('collect')

  -- for memory leakage debugging

  print ('locals')
  for x, v in pairs(locals()) do
      if type(v) == 'userdata' then
        print(x, v:size())
      end
  end

  print ('upvalues')
  for x,v in pairs(upvalues()) do
     if type(v) == 'userdata' then
        print(x, v:size())
      end
  end

end -- ii

print(string.format('Loss: %.4f  Epoch: %d   grad-norm: %.4f',
current_loss[1], ep, torch.norm(parameters)/torch.norm(gradParameters)))

if (current_loss[1] ~= current_loss[1] or gradParameters ~= gradParameters) then
    print ('nan loss or gradParams. quiting...')
    abort()
end

 -- some validation code here
 end --epochs
 print('Training completed')

 end
```

Comment: You created `in_1` and `in_2` as global variables, why are you expecting them to be garbage? Also, `in` is a [keyword](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2) and can't be used for names.

Comment: As a reference link to global variables and garbage collection: "any object stored in a global variable is not garbage for Lua, even if your program will never use it again." https://www.lua.org/pil/17.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention in the snippet. The variables were actually declared local.

Comment: Did you see my answer. You have to call GC out from var scope. but in you first examples GC should be able clean all `ip` vars. But ofcourse it also may be depend on `someImageProcessing` code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for looking into the issue. Finally I managed to hunt down the issue. The issue has nothing to do with my code. It was in the Torch matio library. Matio's load function leaks memory when used in a loop. The issue is discussed here https://github.com/soumith/matio-ffi.torch/issues/1. In my code, loadNext() uses matio for loading input files. Now I am converting all the mat files into .t7 flies before hand as a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

As @Adam said in the comment, `in_1` and `in_2` variables continue to be referenced and their values can't be garbage collected. Even if you change them to be local variables, they won't be garbage collected at that point as the block in which they are defined is not closed yet.

What you can do is to set `in_1` and `in_2` values to `nil` before calling `collectgarbage`, which should make the previously assigned values to be unreachable and eligible for garbage collection. This will only work if there is no other variable that may be storing the same value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Paul's answer above; but note the word "should". Almost all of the time you will be fine. However if e.g. your code gets more complicated (and you start passing memory objects around and working on them), you may find that occasionally the Lua gc may decide to hold onto a memory object just for a little bit longer than expected. But don't worry (*or waste time trying to work out why*), eventually all unused memory objs will be collected by the Lua gc. A garbage collector is a complicated algorithm and can appear a little non-deterministic at times.

Answer (score 0):

You create global variables to store values. So this variables will be avaliable all the time. So until you rewrite values it such vars gc can not collect them.
Just make vars local and call gc out from scope.
Also first cycle of GC may just call finalizer and second one free memory.
But not sure about that. So you can try call gc twice.

```
function train()
  do
    local in = loadInput()
    local in_1 = someImageProcessing(in)
    local in_2 = someImageProcessing(in)
    network:forward( ...some manipulation on in_1,in_2...)
    network:backward()
  end
    collectgarbage('collect')
    collectgarbage('collect')
    print debug.getlocal -- all local variables.
```

**PS.** `in` is not valid variable name in Lua